# How to model to ignore Coverity Scan C++ 'noexcept' false-positives?

Tags: c++, noexcept, coverity, false-positive

With Coverity starting to recognize C++11 `noexcept` as `throw()`,
it is producing spurious false positives in code calling third-party libraries
like Boost.
Moreover, some code deliberately intents to crash on exception
because the exception in that case is unrecoverable, out-of-contract or bug.

An example Coverity report for this case is:

> CID 178772 (#1 of 1): Uncaught exception (UNCAUGHT_EXCEPT)exn_spec_violation: An exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > is thrown but the throw list throw() doesn't allow it to be thrown. This will cause a call to unexpected() which usually calls terminate().

What is the modelling file to submit to Coverity scan to ignore `noexcept` globally?

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the `user_nodefs.h` file (doesn't exist by default, is referenced by the configs, should exist in the same directory as your `coverity_config.xml`) you can simply add `#define noexcept(x)` - this will turn `noexcept()` into an empty define that will therefore do nothing.

Have you considered using components to exclude third-party defects from your views?

Comment: The submission is done via Travis-CI integration,
so I am not sure where ``coverity_config.xml`` is located.

Comment: The "defanging" approach is problematic
because ``noexcept`` and ``noexcept(...)`` are allowed in the code.
How to defang both of them with a single macro?

Comment: That's a bit more difficult (the answer really is the same for any macro question). You could try using a ppp_translator instead - you can specify this to `cov-configure` via `--xml-option`. For example, `cov-configure ... '--xml-option=append_arg:--ppp_translator=replace/noexcept\s*(\(.*\))?/'`. The ppp_translator takes a regex and applies before the pre-processor takes effect (ppp stands for 'pre-pre-process') so you can also use it to massage the code into a form that is more macro-friendly as well.